# 2022 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

[Moderator election #2](https://politics.stackexchange.com/election/2) on Politics — your "graduation" election! — has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderators are:

[image: CDJB]

[image: JJJ]

[image: ohwilleke]

[image: Philipp]

They will be replacing the "old" pro-tem crew [as "regular" mods](https://politics.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly (though most of them were that "old" crew anyway) — please thank them for volunteering, both for running in this election and for their time spent during the site's beta!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://politics.stackexchange.com/election/2) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/4842435011149824).

Comment: Most rounds I've seen on one of the smaller sites

Answer (score 25):

Holy shit! I was sure somebody else would win. Bugger me.

Oh well. I'll try to figure out how to do this in  the next little bit.

> They will be replacing the "old" pro-tem crew as "regular" mods
> shortly (though most of them were that "old" crew anyway) — please
> thank them for volunteering, both for running in this election and for
> their time spent during the site's beta!

Thanks so much for volunteering and for running in this election folks!

Comment: I'm quite happy with my honorable 5th place that is well-deserved for running to fill the numbers with negligible participation. Congratulations 

Comment: Congratulations 

Comment: You are our latest mod. I'm happy for you. You will make a good moderator. Congratulations 

Answer (score 24):

Thanks so much to everyone who took part, especially everyone who contributed questions to the candidates or who put themselves out there and nominated themselves! I’m very glad that the community was happy enough with the existing mod team to re-elect us all :D

Congratulations especially to ohwilleke, I’m looking forward to working with you. Enjoy all the shiny new buttons!

Comment: Congratulations 

Answer (score 21):

Thanks everyone for participating in the election by voting or even running as a candidate! I'm grateful for the renewed confidence in myself and the others on the pro-tem team.

I'm happy to welcome ohwilleke to the team and I'm sure we'll have a good time moderating the site. :)

Comment: Congratulations 

Comment: I voted for you. You won, I won.

Answer (score 18):

Thank you for showing us moderators your continuous trust and support by reelecting all three of us pro-tempore moderators.

And welcome to the team, ohwilleke.

Comment: I voted for you. You won, I won.

Comment: Congratulations Philipp

Answer (score 14):

Welcome aboard (and back)! I've always felt this site was extremely well moderated and deserving of losing its Beta badge. Well earned and congrats on now being fully 'elected' moderators.

Answer (score 7):

I want to take the opportunity to congratulate everyone, winners and and others that didn't get selected as mods in this election. Those that didn't get selected, please don't feel bad. We are here as a community. Everyone's voice is heard, whatever you feel wrong just say it.

And next time please participate. :)

Your participation made it a better election, please know it.

Comment: I wouldn't expect there to be another election until someone steps down or they decide we need more moderators.

Comment: Whatever, it's next time.. not necessarily next year .

Comment: Just trying to help ensure expectations are correct as elections are done on an as needed basis not on a schedule.

Answer (score 6):

I would imagine that this has to be one of if not *the most* difficult stack to moderate.

I know I've had my differences with some of you in the past on meta but hopefully with the understanding that it's a difficult volunteer position. I'm continuously grateful for the work you do, all of you, and thanks so much and congratulations!